# In MongoDB how to find all documents which are in my list of ObjectId's?

Tags: mongodb

I have a list of ObjectId's _id's and I want all the documents which match these ids, is there an efficient way to find these objects in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, use the `$in` operator.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in

Example usage:

```
var arr = [ObjectId("52b11a1a3055376e9e00003d"), ObjectId("52b11a1a3055376e9e00003d")]
db.collection.find({_id: {$in: arr}})
```

Answer (score 0):

The [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator takes an array of arguments so what you want to do is supply all of your `ObjectId` values in a list to that:

```js
var list = [ObjectId("53cf334bb3b0796e36d42184"),ObjectId("53cf3358b3b0796e36d42185")];
db.collection.find({ "_id": { "$in": list } })
```

Also see other [query operators in the manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/):

Answer (score 0):

How about the $in operator as follows:

```
db.collection.find({_id: {$in : [ObjectId("505bd76785ebb509fc183733"), ObjectId("505bd76785ebb509fc183734")] }});
```